# How to fire an event when JTable is visible?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, componentlistener

I would like to know whether `JTable` is not responding to `ComponentListener`. I have a `JTable` inside a tab of a `JTabbedPane`, and I have implemented the `ComponentListener` to the `JTable` so I can fire an even when the table is visible. But, it is not responding!I also noticed it is not responding to `JTabbedPane` as well! any ideas about how you can find whether a JTable is visible?

Comment: It's a pretty straight forward question. But at the same time, for those (like myself) where the answer isn't known off the top of the head, but would like to test, it would be nice to have a [simple runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to play with, that we don't have to write up ourselves. It'll give you a broader audience, considering some are too lazy to write one up. Just an FYI

Comment: @peeskillet: Yea, cool, will update the question.

Comment: Just curious - In this context, is the `JTable` becoming visible, the same as the tab with the table being shown?

Comment: i think you should use jTableComponentShown EVENT